# Generate a view with parent - child taxonomy terms

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

Is there any way that I can create a view of parent-child taxonomy terms that would look alot like this? I was thinking I could use the parent relationship and then group terms and print in a grid but there is no options for parents to be a group field.

http://www.amazon.com/gp/site-directory/ref=nav_shopall_btn

Answer (score 1):

I figured the answer. There is a relationship select box that appears on existing fields. I had to add twice the name field, make one of them use the parent relationship and exclude it from display and then use this as a grouping variable for the grid.

[image]